# Unfiltered raw MarkDown shown in question summary

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, markdown-preview

[image]
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777563/how-to-bind-two-columns-with-eachother-in-gridview) has a picture right at the start of it. This results in the raw Markdown being shown in the question summary (as illustrated). This Markdown needs to be filtered out.

Thinking that I would be clever, I tried to reproduce the 'problem' with this Meta post, but I see that the markdown is not included in the Meta summary. Is it intentional that Meta and SO have different behaviour in that respect?

*Edit: clearly I wasn't clever enough and my Meta post was correctly Markdown'd.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preview shows this snippet:

```
![The diagram][1]
```

But nowhere in the rest of the post (before the fix (and before the cache version)) is there an accompanying reference for that `[1]`. Therefore, it's invalid Markdown.

As such, the question preview is showing as expected since it's just going to dump it out as though it was normal text.